# Not able to get item from DynamoDB through React form-submit but through standalone nodejs code it is working

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-router, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to query `DynamoDB` for a simple login screen. I am using `ReactJS`

```
export  class Login extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.props = props;

    this.state = {
      caffeID: "",
      password: "",
      validUser: false
    };
  }

  validateForm() {
    return this.state.caffeID.length > 0 && this.state.password.length > 0;
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      [event.target.id]: event.target.value
    });
  }

  handleSubmit (event){
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.props);

   // console.log("hoooolllla ..Caffe ID is "+this.state.caffeID+" and password is "+this.state.password);
    console.log("checking from db");
    var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({apiVersion: '2012-08-10'});
    console.log("Caffe ID ==> "+this.state.caffeID);
    var params = {
            TableName: 'caffeuser',
            Key: {'caffeid': this.state.caffeID}
     };

       var value=    docClient.get(params, function(err, data) {
               console.log("Querying database..");
             if (err) {
               console.log("Error", err);
             } else {
               console.log("Success", data.Item);
             }
           });
  }

  render() {

      if (this.state.validUser === true) {

          console.log("Redirecting to login screen... .");
          return <Redirect to='/table' />
        };

    return (

      <div className="Login">

        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>
          <FormGroup controlId="caffeID" bsSize="large">
            <ControlLabel>Caffe ID</ControlLabel>
            <FormControl
              autoFocus
              type="caffeID"
              value={this.state.caffeID}
              onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
            />
          </FormGroup>
          <FormGroup controlId="password" bsSize="large">
            <ControlLabel>Password</ControlLabel>
            <FormControl
              value={this.state.password}
              onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
              type="password"
            />
          </FormGroup>
          <Button
            block
            bsSize="large"
            disabled={!this.validateForm()}
            type="submit"
          >
            Login
          </Button>
        </form>
      </div>



    );
  }
}

export default Login;
```

Now , the code for connecting and querying Dynamodb seems to have stuck.

[image]

But , if I run the same piece of code as a standalone node js code , it runs perfectly.

Here is Node Js code

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
//Set the region 
AWS.config.update({region: 'us-east-2',
 accessKeyId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
secretAccessKey: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx'    
});

 var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({apiVersion: '2012-08-10'});
    var params = {
            TableName: 'caffeuser',
            Key: {'caffeid': 'C0001'}
     };

           docClient.get(params, function(err, data) {
               console.log("Querying database..");
             if (err) {
               console.log("Error", err);
             } else {
               console.log("Success", data.Item);
```

Here is result from Node JS code

```
Querying database..
Success { caffeid: 'C0001', password: 'abc123' }
```

Can you please point me where am I doing wrong ? Should I use `async`-`await` for this scenario ?

============================================

Edit 6th November , 2018,

I have uploaded the screenshot of the request.

Comment: How do you authorize in browser ? In node.js you do `AWS.config.update`. In browser what are you doing instead?

Comment: I am doing the same thing in React JS too..

Comment: Hi @CanSahin , one more thing , I am doing this database query operation in non render function . So , will it involve browser here ?

Comment: config in react is not visible in your code. Thats why I asked. Inside render or outside shouldn't matter. Both are js functions. Can you share the details of that request screenshot that is stuck. I cannot think of specific reason why it doesnt work. Maybe `cors` issue? Maybe credentials issue. Hard to guess

Comment: hi @CanSahin , thanks a lot for your reply. here is is screenshot of request that is stuck : https://imgur.com/a/y2S5q3u

Comment: Hi @CanSahin , one more thing , this `AWS` variable I am importing from another js file . `import AWS from "components/Database/database.jsx";` . And the content of database.jsx is this : `var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
//Set the region 
AWS.config.update({region: 'us-east-2',
    accessKeyId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    secretAccessKey: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    dynamoDbCrc32: false
    
});

export default AWS;`

Comment: Hmm. I honestly have no clue. If you thing that the post parameters are right (which I cant see) then I cannot think of why. Its not giving you back authorization error so your config must be successfully applying. By the way acccesing dynamodb in client side is not a good way to go. Consider hiding it behind your back-end. Or use cognito credentials for temporary access to your dynamodb.

Comment: hi @CanSahin , can I use express js to do query from dynamodb from this react code ? But , in that case also , this issue will come ,right ?

Comment: ExpressJs? Its a node web application library. Has nothing to do with client side and especially in your case. I suggest you find an example or best practices for dynamodb. I hardly think you can find examples accessing dynamodb with credentials in browser. I cannot help in this case. I cannot figure out why because I never had that need. I will never have.